# Check if list of strings contains string sequence

Tags: python

is there a method in python that would check for that and it has to be in the same order.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['b', 'c']

if a contains b:
   c = remove b from a

c = ['a']
```

and if b = `['c', 'b']`
c should be equal to a, c = `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: As far as I understand, this is not a duplicate (of the linked question) as it implies *removing* the sublist if present *in the given order*.

Comment: Let's say `a = ['b','b','b']` and `b = ['b','b']`.  What would you want `c` to be?

Comment: This case can't happen since b should only contain different values.

Comment: Okay, then let's say you have `['b','b','c','c']` and `['b','c']`.  What do you want to get out?

Comment: c would be ['b', 'c']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this problem in two steps:

1. Find the index of the sublist.
2. Remove the sublist given its index in the list.

To find the index of the sublist you can do this:

```
def index(l, s):
    len_s = len(s)
    for pos in range(len(l) - len_s + 1):
        if l[pos:pos + len_s] == s:
            return pos
    return -1
```

It's not as efficient as [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) but it will work for now. Once you have the index, you can simply delete the slice. So your code becomes:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['b', 'c']

pos = index(a, b)
if pos >= 0:
    c = list(a)
    del c[pos:pos + len(b)]

# c = ['a']
```

Comment: if a is ['rtz', 'qwe', 'asd', 'qwe'] and b is ['asd', 'qwe']
it yields ['r', 't', 's', 'd', ' ', 'q', 'w', 'e']
but the result should be ['rtz', 'qwe']

Comment: It works for me. Try this in your interpreter: `a = ['rtz', 'qwe', 'asd', 'qwe']; b = ['asd', 'qwe']; pos = index(a, b); c = a[:]; del c[pos:pos + len(b)]; c`

Comment: hmm, strange I wonder what I did back there ;), seems to work now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your list only contains characters, you can definitely write

```py
print ''.join(b) in ''.join(a)
```

Output:

```
True
```

This does not work, e.g. if `a = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']` and `b = ['bc', 'd']`. It yields `True`, because `bcd` is in `abcdefghi`.

But you can write:

```
print '@'+'@'.join(b)+'@' in '@'+'@'.join(a)+'@'
```

In case `a` or `b` contain items with character `'@'` you might replace it by some unused character.

Comment: `'-'.join(b) in '-'.join(a)` ?

Comment: @Sorin: That's what I thought about as well. But it doesn't solve the problem. ```bc-d``` is still in ```abc-def-ghi```.